# Scraping Links With Unique ID's PHP/Curl

Tags: php, regex, curl

I am attempting to scrape video links on the results page of a youtube search, however I am having trouble as all of the video links contain unique id's. Here's the code I have so far:

```
<?php

$data = file_get_contents('http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=php');

$regex = '/watch?v={11}/';

preg_match($regex,$data,$match);

print_r($match);

?>
```

When printing it out I just get an empty array so it doesn't appear to be picking up on '/watch?v=' or my attempt to dynamically grab the 11 character uid following it.

Comment: escape "?" with "\?" and try again. what happens?

Comment: and add "([^\&])" before "{11}".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in your regex. Moreover you want tu use preg_match_all to get all matches ..

```
$data = file_get_contents('http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=php');

$regex = '/watch\?v=([a-zA-Z0-9_]{11})/';

preg_match_all($regex,$data,$matches);

print_r($matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

`{11}` indicates that the pattern before it must occur exactly 11 times.  That is, you are tring to match 11 equals signs.  You want to change that to `.{11}` .. this may not work very well, but at least you'll get results.